# MouseButtonEventArgs.GetPostion & MouseEventArgs.GetPostion

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, wpfdatagrid

I am trying to do a drag and drop in DataGrid View.

I have my DataGrid is defined inside a user control and the user control is hosted inside a tabcontrol

Now i am handling the following events

```
PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" 
PreviewMouseMove="OnPreviewMouseMove"
```

the handlers are defined as follows;

```
private void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Point mousePos = e.GetPosition(null);
    Vector diff = startPoint - mousePos;

    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed &&
        (Math.Abs(diff.X) > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance ||
        Math.Abs(diff.Y) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance))
    {
        // .......doing drag/drop work here.......
    }
}

private void OnPreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    startPoint = e.MouseDevice.GetPosition(null);
}
```

where startPoint is the internal variable of type Point

However always the vector diff inside OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown function is always zero.

to my surprise the same logic works inside a triewview control but not inside a the datagrid?
any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You always get a MouseMove event immediately before the LeftButtonDown event, so startPoint will always be the same as mousePos with your current code.

Swapping your handlers should fix it (code in PreviewLeftButtonDown should be in PreviewMouseMove, and startPoint should be set in PreviewLeftButtonDown).